# Order by Field in non-alphabetical order in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to order items by a list of names that are not in alphabetical order. After completing the list I am trying to continue the rest in alphabetical order without the ones I initially selected.

See example:

**INPUT:**

```
print 'Results:'  
select * from Geniuses
    order by ('Charles Babbage', 
              'Albert Einstein', 
              'Adrien-Marie Legendre', 
              'Niels Henrik Abel')
```

then finally sort the rest in alphabetical order...

**OUTPUT:**

```
Results:
Charles Babbage ... details
Albert Einstein ...
Adrien-Marie Legendre ...
Niels Henrik Abel ...
Arthur Cayley ...
...
```

Comment: Is your initially selected list finite or dynamic?

Comment: Its finite like a small list of favorite Geniuses that were choosen by a specific user.  But another user might choose different ones from the same list of Geniuses.

Comment: Ok, then it's dynamic.  Sorry, I meant static instead of finite...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select * from Geniuses
order by
    -- First, order by your set order...
    case FullName
        when 'Charles Babbage' then 1
        when 'Albert Einstein' then 2
        when 'Adrien-Marie Legendre' then 3
        when 'Niels Henrik Abel' then 4
        else 5 
    end,
    -- Then do a secondary sort on FullName for everyone else.
    FullName
```

EDIT:

I saw your comment that it's configurable by each user.  In that case, you'd have to have a `FavoriteGeniuses` table that tracks which user prefers which `Geniuses`, and then have a sort order specified in that table:

```
select * 
from 
    Geniuses g left join
    FavoriteGeniuses fg 
        ON fg.GeniusID = g.GeniusID 
        AND fg.UserID = @UserID
order by
    -- The higher the number, the first up on the list.
    -- This will put the NULLs (unspecified) below the favorites.
    fg.SortPriority DESC, 
    f.FullName
```

Answer (score 4):

Try it like this:

```
select * from Geniuses
order by
   case when columnName = 'Charles Babbage' then 0
     when columnName = 'Albert Einstein' then 1
     when columnName = 'Adrien-Marie Legendre' then 2
     when columnName = 'Niels Henrik Abel' then 3
     else 4
     end,
   columName
```