# SQL Custom Order By Clause

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

A quick Question. I have a query that brings back 2 columns 'Description' and 'Amount'
In the Description we have 3 outcomes.

'Gold - owned', 'Bronze - no land' and 'Silver - identified / offered'

I would like the result to show in an order of 
Gold,Silver,Bronze

Order By Asc or Desc does not achieve this. Is there a way to customize a Order by clause?

Any Help on this Would be appreciated thanks
Rusty

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Something similar has been achieved for SQL Server here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9132760/1854461

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside of a `CASE`, you may ascribe a numeric value to each and order those ascending.  If you will need to query a large table, consider adding an index on `Description` to improve sorting performance.

```
ORDER BY
  CASE 
    WHEN Description = 'Gold - owned' THEN 0
    WHEN Description = 'Silver - identified / offered' THEN 1
    WHEN Description = 'Bronze - no land' THEN 2
    ELSE 99 /* Any other value (which you should not have) sorts after all */
  END ASC  /* And don't forget to be explicit about ASC order though it's the default */
```

Since this works like a normal column in the `ORDER BY`, if you needed to then sort by the `Amount` or other column, it can be appended with a comma.

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE
    WHEN Description = 'Gold '...
  END ASC,
  Amount DESC,
  AnotherColumn ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) statement:

```
ORDER BY ( CASE Description
              WHEN 'Gold - owned' THEN 1
              WHEN 'Silver - identified / offered' THEN 2
              WHEN 'Bronze - no land' THEN 3
              ELSE 0
            END)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your order by Clause

**order by case description when 'gold' then 1 
              when 'silver'then 2 
               else 3 end asc**

Answer (score 0):

Use **CASE** in **ORDER BY** Clause:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE Description
  WHEN ='Gold - owned' THEN 1
  WHEN = 'Silver - identified / offered' THEN 2
  WHEN = 'Bronze - no land' THEN 3
ELSE 4 END
```

Answer (score -1):

`ORDER BY`

`ORDER BY` clause is used to sort data in ascending or descing order.

By default it orders by ascending order if the order is not mentioned.

Syntax:

To order by asc/desc order –

```
SELECT column_name1,column_name2,… column_nameN   FROM table_name WHERE condition ORDER BYcolumn_name [ASC | DESC];
```

Example :

```
SELECT CustomerId , Name FROM customer_details WHERE CustomerId> 0 ORDER BY CustomerId;
```

http://academy.comingweek.com/sql-orderby/