# Custom ORDER BY Function SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have requirements for a custom ORDER BY clause that looks much like this

[SQL Custom Order By Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909406/sql-custom-order-by-clause)

```
SELECT * FROM example
ORDER BY 
CASE 
    WHEN name = 'I want this first' THEN 0
    WHEN name = 'I want this second' THEN 1
    WHEN name = 'We get the picture' THEN 2
    ELSE 99   END ASC
```

However, this case statement has grown and I want to be able to reuse the sort order for other queries.

I see my options being

1. Copy Paste!
2. Adding another column to the table specifically for this sort order

In my head, it seems like I should be able to pass a function to perform the sorting logic. But after some searching on SO and google I couldn't find anything and thought this might also help someone else down the road.

Comment: Use a INLINE User Defined Function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is a CTE:

```
with ordering as (
      select v.*
      from (values(1, 'val1'), (2, 'val2'), (3, 'val3')) v(priority, val)
    )
select e.*
from example e
order by (select priority from ordering o where o.val = e.name);
```

I would discourage you from doing an explicit `join`, because that could affect the semantics of the query.  A `join` filters the records *before* the `select`, `where`, `group by`, and `having` clauses are processed (logically).  The `order by` only uses results in the result set (logically).

You can, of course, store the CTE values in a temporary table or table variable.  That might be what you are after.

Another approach is a bit of a hack, but works under some circumstances.  You can replace the logic with:

```
order by charindex('[' + name + ']', '[name1][name2][name]')
```

This assumes that all names are in the list.  And that names don't have the delimiter characters. This doesn't directly solve your problem, but you can store the string as a variable in a code block or even as a computed column in a table.

Answer (score 5):

Create a second table with two columns (name, rank)

```
SELECT * 
FROM example e INNER JOIN table2 t2 on e.name = t2.name
ORDER BY t2.rank ASC;
```

And your second table will contain the pairings.

Comment: I would discourage this approach because a `JOIN` can affect the semantics of the query.

Comment: Huh, I always just assumed the db would be smart enough to optimize. Thanks for commenting otherwise I never would have read your answer and learned this.

Comment: The following query might not produce the same results:  `select e.*, count(*) over () from example`.